# Proposition about of Purely inseparable extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

In the Book's Algebra, Lang, page 251.

Proposition: Let $E^p$  denote the field of all elementos $x^p$, $x\in E$- Let $E$ be a finite extension of $k$. If  $E^pk=E$, then $E$ is separable over $k$.

Proof:Let $E_0$ be the maximal separable subfield of $E$. Let $E=k(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$. Since $E$ is purely inseparable over $E_0$ there exists $m$ such that $\alpha_i^{p^m}\in E_0$ for each $i=1,\ldots,n$. Hence $E^{p^m}\subset E_0$ . But $E^{p^m}k=E$ whence $E=E_0$ is separable over $k$.

$\textbf{My question's are:}$

1) Why can the same $m$ be used for all the $\alpha_i's$, rather than different $m_i's$?

2)  Please explain why $E^pk=E$ implies $E^{p^m}k=E$
Thank you all.

Comment: It is not clear what question $1$ is. You can write it in Spanish and we can translate it.

Comment: Listo, lo acabo de escribir en español.

Comment: The question seems to be: 1) Why can the same $m$ be used for all the $\alpha_i$'s, rather than different $m_i$'s? 2) Please explain why $E^p k = E$ implies $E^{p^m}k = E$.

Comment: En cuanto a (1), a cada $\alpha_i$ corresponde un $m_i$ que funciona. Lang toma el mayor entre ellos.

Comment: Para el punto (2), ¿podrías ayudarme? Gracias.

Comment: Mejor dicho, puede tomar el mayor. Para (2), suponé que $E^{p^{m-1}}k = E$. Aplicá el endomorfismo de Frobenius a cada miembro. Entonces $E^{p^m}k^p = E^p$, así que $E^{p^m}k = E^{p^m}k^p k = E^p k = E$

Comment: Although I am also tempted to speak some Spanish, I recommend we stick to English since the comments will be helpful for future reference. In fact @user208259 I encourage you post an answer (and include a Spanish translation if you want to.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I don't mind translating on request if someone feels this is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), there's some $m_i$ that works for each $\alpha_i$. It's enough to let $m$ be the largest of these.

For $(2)$, assume that $E^{p^{m-1}}k = E$. Apply the Frobenius endomorphism to each side of this equality to obtain $E^{p^m} k^p = E^p$, hence $E^{p^m} k = E^{p^m} k^p k = E^p k = E$.

Comment: Podrías explicarme porque $E^{p^m}k=E^{p^m}k^pk$. No lo entiendo bien. Gracias.

Comment: No pierdas de vista que $k^p \subseteq k$.

Comment: Es verdad, muchas gracias.